# How read AArch64 register in AArch32 mode

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, arm64, raspberry-pi4

i have a raspberry pi4 board that powered with Cortex-A72 processor. in this processor exist a special register that named "ID_AA64PFR0_EL1". document of Cortex-A72 explains:

> To access the ID_AA64PFR0_EL1 in AArch64 state, read the register with:
>   MRS , ID_AA64PFR0_EL1; Read AArch64 Processor Feature Register 0

as document indicated with above command we could read ID_AA64PFR0_EL1 register in AArch64 mode. but official raspbian os only support AArch32 mode. so i want to know there is anyway that let me read ID_AA64PFR0_EL1 register in AArch32 mode?

Comment: would assume that's not possible. notice how the aarch32 registers are documented as how to access through aarch32 and how to access through aarch64?  but not the aarch64 registers.  you cant do anything aarch64 from aarch32 (but you can in the other direction by dropping a level into aarch32) so why would you want/need this.

Comment: According to [this question on raspberrypi.SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/100926), Raspbian can run with a 64bit kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's possible to get access to ID_AA64PFR0_EL1 in AArch32 mode.

According to "Architecture Reference Manual ARMv8"

> ID_AA64PFR0_EL1, AArch64 Processor Feature Register 0 
> ...
> Configurations
> AArch64 System register ID_AA64PFR0_EL1 is architecturally mapped to
> **External register EDPFR**

> EDPFR, External Debug Processor Feature Register
> EDPFR[31:0] can be accessed through the internal memory-mapped interface

According to same "Architecture Reference Manual ARMv8" and "ARM® Cortex®-A72 MPCore Processor, Technical Reference Manual"

> To access the ID_AA64PFR0_EL1 in AArch64 state, read the register
> with: 
> `MRS <Xt>, ID_AA64PFR0_EL1; Read AArch64 Processor Feature Register 0` 
> The `ID_AA64PFR0[31:0]` can be accessed through the
> memory-mapped interface and the external debug interface, offset
> `0xD20`. 
> `The ID_AA64PFR0[63:32]` can be accessed through the
> memory-mapped interface and the external debug interface, offset
> `0xD24`.

So you should check **manufacturing** documentation on your chip, and find out at what address "debug interface" is mapped. 
After that read `[addr + 0xd20]` & `[addr + 0xd24]`

Enjoy.